# Crystal field therory and high-to-low spin state transition

Tags: quantum-spin

Following is a paragraph from one of the papers I am reading. In this paragraph, the author tries to compare the energy difference between high and low spin states for d6 and d5 ions. However, he/she didn't put any caption about the meaning for each parameter and I am having a hard time understanding it. Could anyone help me explain this? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- $V$ is the electrostatic (i.e. Coulomb) repulsion the two electrons feel from being in the same orbital. Often in physics, this is denoted as $U$, and referred to as the Hubbard $U$.
- $J$ is the Hund's coupling. This is also referred to as the exchange coupling. If this seems new, recall from chemistry that spins on an atom like to align. $J$ here is the energy of this coupling. You can see this for yourself from the paragraph you've posted: The energy of the anti-aligned spin configuration is $V+2J$ and the energy of the aligned spin configuration is $V-J$. Anti-aligning the spins costs energy $2J$ while aligning the spins lowers the energy by $J$.
- The crystal field splitting $\Delta$ comes from the energy difference between the various $d$ orbitals. If the Fe atom is floating around in free space, all of the $d$ orbitals would have the same energy. However, the Fe atom is actually sitting in a molecule (or crystal, depending on what you're looking at). As such, the electrons on the Fe atom feel the Coulomb potential of the atoms around it. This leads to a splitting in the energies of the previously degenerate $d$ orbitals. This is the phenomenon known as crystal field splitting. The splitting depends on the geometry of the situation, but commonly, the cation (here Fe) sits inside an octahedron of Oxygens. In this case, one can show via group theory that the previously 5-fold degenerate energy level splits into a 2-fold degenerate level and a 3-fold degenerate level. I'm of course ignoring spin here. If you want to include spin, multiply these degeneracies by 2.

Hopefully, the above comments are enough to help you read your paper.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps a lot but I still have trouble reproducing delta_E. Could I ask a follow-up question? Let's consider d5 without crystal field splitting for simplicity. In high spin state, all five orbitals are singly occupied with parallel spins, the total E=5(V-J). In lows spin, two orbitals are doubly occupied, the total E for the four electrons is 2*2(V+2J). But what about the electron that occupies one orbital by itself? It is parallel to two of the electrons and antiparallel to the other two. What should I use for its energy?

Comment: Sorry for another message. I think I understand where I messed up. For example, in d5 low spin, I have to consider the repulsion between every two electrons. In other words, the total should be C(5,2) * (V-J), where C(5, 2) calculates the combination. Please correct me if this is wrong. Another question I have though is the details about Hund's coupling, for example, why does the two orbitals antiparallel alignment give V but parallel give V-J? Could you elaborate on this or point me to the right paper/textbook? Thanks a lot!